# How and why is kinematic control implemented?

Tags: control-theory, dynamics, kinematics

First off, I apologize for what is likely a rather broad and formless question (and an even more broad and formless title). I'm a mathematician whose work sometimes carries him to control systems due to its endless supply of real-world applications. As such, I am by no means versed in the literature, and my knowledge of implementation of control schemes is fairly limited.

Usually, control enters my work in the form a trajectory-tracking. That is, we have some dynamical system
\begin{align*}
\ddot{x} &= f(x, u)
\end{align*}
where $x(t)$ represents the state of the system, and $u$ is some control. The aim is to design $u$ so that $x(t)$ converges (say asymptotically) to some desired trajectory $\hat{x}(t)$.

As an application of a recent problem I considered, the idea of "kinematic control" came to my attention for the first time, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what is physically happening in such a system. Until now, I've universally thought of controllers as designable external forces applied to some system. Being forces, the controllers arise naturally in the *dynamics* of the system. So the very idea of controlling only the kinematics seems, well, non-physical.

My guess as to what is actually happening with kinematic control is that we design the velocities first (as some "pseudo" kinematic control $v$), and then design the "physical" control in the dynamics so that the kinematics converge to $\dot{x} = v$. In such a case, I suppose the end goal is no longer to track a trajectory, but rather that $x$ converges to some end-point $\hat{x}$.

In particular, in the above dynamical system, we first seek to design the kinematic control so that, with $\dot{x} = v$, we have $x(t) \to \hat{x}$ asymptotically. From there, we design $u$ so that $x$ converges to the desired trajectory given by $\hat{x}(t) = \int v(t) dt$. Seemingly, such a strategy just made the problem more difficult (as we still needed to design the trajectory tracking controller for the dynamics in the end), so I'm guessing that either 1) there's some way that people get around this issue after designing $v$, 2) we gain some advantage in designing $v$ first that I'm unaware of, or 3) I'm totally off base to begin with. Could someone please offer some insight?

Comment: It depends on what the goal is and how accumulated position and time errors are corrected, if at all. It also depends on where the electromechanical transition occurs. In the case of PIGAs, they integrate acceleration mechanically and produce a pulse output. The controller just counts the pulses and that is the measured velocity. So the control scheme is done entirely in velocity space. There is a reference trajectory precomputed in velocity space. The onboard telemetry is compared, and appropriate action is taken.

Comment: Why? because six guys figured out how to do this about ten years before integrated circuits were a thing. They had a particular 6 dof problem in mind, less than 1k of program storage, and a disk that worked like a delay line. Oh, they wanted about 50 binary digits of velocity accuracy after 10 minutes of inertial flight. Apparently, the trick was that the errors were less when linearizing in velocity space than when linearizing in position space.

Comment: In the controls literature it's usually $\dot x = f(x, u)$, i.e. $\frac {dx}{dt}$, not $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$.  Typo?

Comment: @TimWescott One can always consider a second-order ODE as a  system of first-order ODEs by defining $v = \dot{x}$, and then $\dot{v} = f(x, u)$. What I mean to say is that most "physical" dynamical systems (with or without control) arise from Newton's law or, more generally, the Euler-Lagrange equations, both of which relate accelerations of the state variables to the external forces. As far as I can see, acting upon such a system to modify its behavior (via a controller) necessitates some external force that we can design, which must then appear in the dynamics.

Comment: OK, that's fine.  But if there's a damper in the mix, then $F = ma$ does not hold -- and most control systems would model a plant with a damper as $F = ma + bv$, and call the $F$ the external force.  Consider that you're coming to us for answers, but first you want us to throw away our decades of experience and do things according to your preconceptions -- if we do that, will you get good answers?

Comment: @TimWescott There's no issue with velocity dependent forces, they are simply non-conservative, and the dynamics would nevertheless come from Newton's Law or the Lagrange d'Alembert principle. The equations of motion would just be modified to be $\ddot{x} = f(x, \dot{x}, u)$. I don't wish for you to throw away your experience, I'm just translating the problems into a language that I understand.

Comment: @TomWescott In effect, I'm only looking to understand how a control would arise naturally in the kinematics of a system, rather than the dynamics.  In my limited understanding, a control would correspond to, say, the spinning of a propeller (which affects the system via a lift force), the acceleration of a vehicle, etc. All of which would affect the system via its dynamics. If we were to control only the velocities, what would physically be happening in the system so that we were able to generate this velocity while continuing to safisfy the dynamics?

Answer (score 0):

"Controllers" as such do *not* arise naturally in dynamical systems. The velocities and displacements in any dynamical system are established by how the masses and compliances that are present in the system are connected together. A *controller* consists of embedded dynamics and velocity and displacement detectors whose job it is to externally perturb the overall system to urge one of its state variables to some desired value.

The mathematics to do this is enormously simplified by Fourier-transforming a representation of the dynamical system into the *s*-domain, solving it there, and then transforming it back for implementation. This is the standard methodology of *automatic control theory*.